# Moving vertical scroll bar as keyboard navigation happens in custom div dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, keyboard-events

I am navigating through the options in a custom dropdown( simulated using div) using the keyboard navigation(up, down and enter keys). I want the scroll bar to move and adjust to show the option properly as i navigate using keyboard. If anyone can give in their insight, It will be helpful.

Code present here ---> http://jsbin.com/uvotat/13/edit

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding this at the end of your function `change_selection` :

```
if( $('.selected').position().top + $('.results').height() >= $('.results').scrollTop()+$('.results').height()){
    $('.results').scrollTop($('.selected').position().top - $('.results').height() + $('.results').scrollTop())
}else if($('.selected').position().top <= $('.results').scrollTop()){
        $('.results').scrollTop(0 + $('.selected').position().top)
}
```

Fiddle : http://jsbin.com/uvotat/15/edit

Comment: @Karl-André Gagnon I have exactly same issue but I want solution in JavaScript, could you please help?

Comment: @HappyDev The short answer is no, but i will gladly help if you make another question with more explaination and your current code! You can then link it here. Without jquery, this problem is a little bit more complicated

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Thank u for responding, actually it is a very complex code thats y I didnt post it here but I posted a query earlier u can see it , here is the link <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17938661/arrow-keys-are-not-working-in-dropdown>

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon this is not working properly if there are many items, i tried to achieve the same thing with more than 30 items in the list, but it is not working properly..

Comment: @RohitBisht To be honest, this code is old and unreliable, you should use an already existing library such as Select2 to make custom dropdown. The support is way better than this old snippet.